# Android checkbox preferences and extra options

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferencescreen

Is it possible to setup an android checkbox preferences or list preferences to add more or less items to a preferences screen? If so how can I achieve it?

For example I have a simple layout like this:

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="wallpaper-type"
    android:title="Choose Wallpaper Style"
    android:entries="@array/wpType"
    android:entryValues="@array/wpTypeValues"
    />
```

there's 3 options in this list. I would like it so that if you choose option 1 you have different selection of menu items that you can choose because each item has different parameters that the user can update.

Similarly if I have this option:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="enable_brightness"
    android:title="Enable Brightness Tap Menu"/>
```

so if the user clicks on this check box, then another preferences menu can be added to the view.

Maybe I am going about this all wrong and should redesign the way I structure my views and options or is it possible to have dynamic options populated from xml preferably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do it is to have define `android:dependency`. Unavailable preference is displayed as disabled instead of gone.

Also in general, if you are using a preference, you would like to save it in SharedPreference by setting `android:persistent="true"`

Here is a sample

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/show_notifications_title"
            android:key="show_notifications"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/show_file_size_error_title"
            android:key="show_file_size_error"
            android:dependency="show_notifications"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, thanks! Also thanks for the persistent tip, that saved me some debugging down the road!